# Ads not showing up in release mode

Tags: android, release, ads

I have an app which is supposed to show some ads. In debug mode, everything runs fine, ads are showing up as they should be.

But in release mode, nothing happens, even though the exact same code is running (and the same URLs are used). I also have multiple environments (test/production), it works fine in test/debug and production/debug but fails in both test/release and production/release.

Note that everything else is working fine in release mode. No relevant topic were found anywhere about this kind of bug.

Comment: You should contact help desk for that service...

Comment: What ad sdk are you using? have you changed your hash key from debug to release (if needed for your sdk)

Comment: sounds like this could be a proguard issue. In your gradle file, under release, set minifyEnabled to false and see if this still happens. If it doesn't you need to add an exclude rule in your proguard file for the API that shows ads.

Comment: @GilMoshayof your solution did the trick ! I excluded from ProGuard everything related to the ad API, and they now show with no issue ! If you want to write a formal answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you confirmed, this is a **Proguard** issue.

Proguard's main function is to minify your code, replacing function names such as "doImportantThing" to "a" etc, making it more light weight and harder to reverse engineer.

A quick fix would be to disable minification by setting `minifyEnabled` to `false` in the gradle release block, however this would mean that Proguard is disabled and does not perform the important functions mentioned earlier.

The **real fix** would be to edit your proguard-rules file, and make sure Proguard excludes certain classes from the minification process.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) is a small guide on how to use & configure Proguard, but you can find a lot more content on the web.

Hope this helps.